# "このオブジェクトに関連付けられているプロセスはありません。" エラーの回避・解決法について

Tags: c#

現在、多重起動防止のためのwindow強制終了の処理にて困っております。

プロセス名によせてPIDを取得しまくり、同プロセス名、違PIDのwindowを強制削除しまくる事で多重起動防止できると考え、調べてみました。検索すると沢山、同様の処理が出てまいりますので参考にしてみたところprocess.CloseMainWindowの箇所にて表題のエラーが発生します。

不思議と、成功する事もあるのでかえって厄介です。

以上、宜しくお願いいたします。

```
System.Diagnostics.Process hThisProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
System.Diagnostics.Process[] hProcesses = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(hThisProcess.ProcessName);
int iThisProcessId = hThisProcess.Id;
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process hProcess in hProcesses){
    if (hProcess.Id != iThisProcessId){
        if (!hProcess.CloseMainWindow()){
            hProcess.Kill(); 
        }
        else{
            Logger.Info("CloseMainWindow成功：" + hProcess.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 相手プロセスを停止させるという手法を採用するということは**後勝ち**を期待してのことでしょうか？ またASP.NETタグは質問と無関係に感じられます。

Comment: そうです、後から開けたwindowを有効にしたいのです。
ASP.NET無関係でしたか。紛らわしいのでタグを削除しておきます。

Answer (score 1):

なんだかすごく危険そうなことをしていますが・・・
現コード全部捨てて Mutex による多重起動チェックにしませんか？
他にも tips が紹介されていますし参照してください。
http://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/process/checkprevinstance.html

あれ？ ASP.NET なの？だとしたらわけがわからんコードなんだけど・・・

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。やはり危険でしたか。Mutex方式に切り替えて行ってみます。
と、すると、今度は"オブジェクト同期メソッドは、コードの非同期ブロックから呼び出されました。"なんてメッセージが。
いやはや道は遠そうです。。

Comment: asyncを指定したメソッドの中などからはそのような例外になり得ます。ShownイベントなどでMutexの判定を行うのはどうでしょうか？[フォームがはじめて表示されたことを知る](http://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/form/noticeformshowed.html)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。結局、MutexもSemaphoreもうまく行かず、FindWindowで見つけ次第WM_CLOSEを送りつける方法で回避しました。